# Apply Lets Encrypt SSL for CNAME URL Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx

**Situation:**

I've created a website that allows users to create their own simple sub-sites. Initially these are on sub-domains (i.e. `newsite.websitecreator.com`).These have SSL applied to them via a wildcard certificate `*.websitecreator.com`. All works fine!

I've also created a means of users being able to purchase a custom domain via an API or route their own domain to point to their subdomain. To achieve this a `CNAME` is created and pointed to the subdomain. This is routing and fine using an include line in the nginx config which includes all the custom domains:

`include /home/forge/websitecreator.com/public/content/websitecreator-customer-domains.conf;`

**Issue**

The main issue is the application of SSL to the custom domains. Obviously the SSL needs to be installed on the server, which has been tried through Forge's LetsEncrypt SSL option within the dashboard, with a view to using the Forge API for future LetsEncrypt when this is automated. However, this is giving me the following error:

```
Cloning into 'letsencrypt15721234230'...
ERROR: Challenge is invalid! (returned: invalid) (result: {
  "type": "http-01",
  "status": "invalid",
  "error": {
    "type": "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized",
    "detail": "Invalid response from http://newcustomdomain.co.uk/.well-known/acme-challenge/Da6CtvOTJnQVHQyENujDSih81TKuejKuaAWCWXsJKus [88.123.456.9]: \"\u003c!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \\\"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN\\\"   \\\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd\\\"\u003e\u003chtml\u003e\u003chead\u003e\u003cmeta http-eq\"",
    "status": 403
  },
  "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/995722342/n7xg9g",
  "token": "Da6CtvOTJnQVhh2h3hn2jbSih81TKuejKuaAWCWXsJKus",
  "validationRecord": [
    {
      "url": "http://newcustomdomain.co.uk/.well-known/acme-challenge/Da6CtvOTJnQVHQyENujDSih81TKuejKuaAWCWXsJKus",
      "hostname": "newcustomdomain.co.uk",
      "port": "80",
      "addressesResolved": [
        "88.123.123.9"
      ],
      "addressUsed": "66.343.234.9"
    }
  ]
})
```

Status code `403` tells me that this is unauthorised for some reason.

**Question**

Despite the approaches tried above, my question is to the SO community is, given the current setup (Forge, Laravel, nginx etc) how would you approach this and any sample code / examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Afraid I didn't then the project died...

Comment: Well sadly, the thing i figured out is that to achieve that you must use forge api to create the other domains as sites and point them to the same files, or you can add them to a site as alias but you must have them in cloudflare(or any other dns manager) as it'll require cloudflare api to use DNS Method instead of file verification. The thing is complex a bit.